# improve a basic login system using radio buttons

Tags: c#

here is my code:

```
public bool radioButtons()
    {
        if (!userRadioButton.Checked && !adminRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must select an account type");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

now, when the username is empty, it brings up the messagebox twice?

Comment: sorry, correct that. The a in                                            radioButtons(a) and if (a == true) are red underlined

Comment: Is `a` a global variable?

Comment: What the red underlined error says ?

Comment: What's `a`? Where it's declared?

Comment: i have just declared a as a bool and the radioButtons(a) is still underlined, saying use of unassigned local variable a. Basically i want the program to run the radioButtons function to check if one is checked, if it is then run the code in the if statement

Comment: sorry guys if this is novice stuff, i should add im just a beginner

Comment: Did you declare the variable before you called your `radioButtons(a)` method?

Comment: yes public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool a;
            radioButtons(a);
            if (a == true)
            {

Comment: I see the problem, do this `public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { bool a = radioButtons(a);  if (a == true) { }`. You declared the variable, but you didn't assign the value from your `radioButtons(a)` method to it.

Comment: i have edited the original post, as another problem has risen

Comment: never mind, needed an else if. But the message box for radio buttons is still coming up twice?

Comment: There is something you are doing. You have to pin point exact problem by posting some of more code.

Comment: @user2827904 Have you tried my code example?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to implement is something like that

```
public bool radioButtons()
{
    if (!userRadioButton.Checked && !adminRadioButton.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must select an account type");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and in button click event.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool a = radioButtons();
    if (a)   
    {
        // a is true do what you want.
    }
}
```

Comment: thats sorted it! but now if the radio button isnt checked, it shows the message box twice?

Comment: Is the button clicked twice?

Comment: no, just once. when i click the register button the message box shows up, the when you click ok, it shows again

Comment: If this code help's you then accept this as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to change 2 things:

1. the `radioButtons` method doesn't need to accept a boolean
2. you should declare `a` first

your code should look like:

```
public bool radioButtons()
{
    if (!userRadioButton.Checked && !adminRadioButton.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must select an account type");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (radioButtons())
    {
       //Your code here
    }
}
```